# Jmeter-How to exclude specific url of recording?

Tags: url, jmeter, exclusionpath

I need a pattern to exclude this url /XXX/XXX/UIDL?windowName=1 of recordings, i try with many patterns but none of them worked

https://i.stack.imgur.com/azqol.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically all you need is to provide a [Perl-5 style regular expression](https://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/regexps.html) which will match this `/XXX/XXX/UIDL?windowName=1` pattern via URL Patterns to Exclude input of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

So you could use something like `.*(UIDL\?windowName=1).*` (question mark is one of meta-characters which needs to be escaped by backslash) and it will do the trick for you.

[image: JMeter Exclude Domain from Recording]

References:

- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)
- [JMeter Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Excluding Domains from the Load Test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test)